# Issue while passing a value from a link to a JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

I have the table data which is displyaed like below, where Dispute Number has a link.

[image]

I have generated the html code using the function below

```
getMessage(result){

for (var j = 0; j < result.invocationResult.resultSet.length; j++) {
    var tmp = "<tr>";
    var resSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet[j];

    for(res in resSet){

               if(res=="DISP_NUMBER")
           var ab = resSet.DISP_NUMBER;

           tmp += "<td><a href="+"#"+" data-role="+" button"+" id="+" button-mainpage" +" onclick="+ " changeToSomePage("+ab+");>"+ab +"</a></td>";

           $("#mytable").append(tmp+"</tr>");
```

When the user clicks on the dispute number link, the below js function gets called. 
I am passing the dispute number with the variable 'ab'. When i alert this value in the function changeToSomePage(ab), 
it works sometimes, sometimes it giving incorrect number.

```
function changeToSomePage(ab) {
alert(ab); 
$('#pagePort').load("pages/disputedetails.html");

}
```

Do you see anything wrong with the above code ? Is this the right apporach to retrieve the value from a link & send it to a JS function when clicked ??

Thanks..Johnson

Comment: First of all, *IDs must be unique*! :)

Comment: rewrite this `"<td><a href="+"#"+" data-role="+" button"+" id="+" button-mainpage" +" onclick="+ " changeToSomePage("+ab+");>"+ab +"</a></td>";`

Comment: And also try to bind events in JS, not inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `ab` is a string. You need to wrap it with quotes.

```
"<td><a href="+"#"+" data-role="+" button"+" id="+" button-mainpage" +" onclick="+ " changeToSomePage(\""+ab+"\");>"+ab +"</a></td>";
```

Of course inline handlers are not the best way. You can use event delegation instead: bind single onclick handler on the table itself.

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.change-to-some-page', function() {
    var num = $(this).data('num');
});
```

And when generating rows.

```
tmp += '<td><a href="#" data-role="button" class="change-to-some-page" ' +  
        'data-num="' + ab + '">' +ab +'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

rewrite this

```
 "<td><a href="+"#"+" data-role="+" button"+" id="+" button-mainpage" +" onclick="+ " changeToSomePage("+ab+");>"+ab +"</a></td>"
```

using double and single quotes - much easier to read. and create unique ids ith the j value

```
  "<td><a href='#' data-role='button' id='button-mainpage-" + j + "' onclick=' changeToSomePage("+ab+");'>"+ab +"</a></td>"
```

Comment: I guess we were typing at the same time.